# Deleting file(s) permanently (unrecoverably) C++

Tags: c++, security, filesystems, delete-file

I am working on an application that will provide user (*Linux & Windows*) with possibility of secure deletion of the file. By *secure deletion* is meant process of repeatedly rewriting the space where the file is stored with zeros and ones, for example three times in a row and then removing the file.

As far as I went with my research, this is file-system related problem and I will need to implement this functionality for most common file-systems, e.g. *FAT, NTFS*.

**Proposed solution:**
Naturaly the security of the code is an issue. Is it that simple that I open the file I want to delete, then overwrite every byte of it with new value, save it, open it again and so on. And THEN I delete it? That would be the solution I can think of, but I have nothing to confirm that (yes, I searched Stack).

**Questions:**

- Is there a different approach considering some sort of NTFS/FAT libraries I have to include, determine what file system I am on and?
- Is it required to remove some sort of cache from RAM or other places after I get rid of the original file?

I have the feeling that opening the file will leave a trace somewhere in the system, possible even file contents, which I would have to remove as well.

Where would you point me to continue with my research before jumping into implementation?

Comment: A really safe delete would have to bypass file system I/O and directly overwrite disk blocks, because some file systems perform rewrites on different disk locations automatically, or perform snapshots of the data.

Comment: @Paulo1205 Alright, that's the kind of response I was looking for. Can you point me anywhere more specific where to study something about it? And how to implement such functionality in C++?

Comment: I don't have all the pointers, but studying filesystem layout might be a start.  You mentioned FAT; its perhaps one of the most well documented FS types around.  Unix/Linux ufs/ffs/ext2fs are probably very easy to get info on, too.

Comment: @FanaticD I recommend looking at an existing open source implementation. Here's [GNU shred](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/shred.c;h=08e212a23dfa5b7d037b1cef8bfdab4117e3185e;hb=HEAD). It's C of course, but trivial to write in C++. It's for POSIX systems though, so if you want to write for windows, you'll need to rewrite most library calls.

Comment: However, keep in mind that directly poking with raw disk data might be difficult/impossible with an open volume on a running system.

Comment: Also note that later Windows versions by default keep a file history to help you restore files that are accidentally overwritten.

Comment: Also, you should know that you can not securely erase on a flash drive (including SSD) at least, not from the file system side. Device specific tools might exist. And on journaling filesystems, you'll need to get rid of the journal which means you'll need to erase the entire partition.